# correct usage of “instead of”

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Would any one let me know the correct usage of *instead of*?

Here, I have written an example.

> In this example case, if we traverse from vertex 2 to 3, *in stead of* vertex 2 to 4, the problem can be solved.

Comment: You use "in lieu of" in lieu of "instead of" why?

Comment: @MετάEd: thought both are same,, I changed it

Comment: Your question is about "instead of". But your example was first "in lieu of", now "in stead of". This is still very confusing. Are you asking about "instead", "in lieu", or "in stead"? Or all three at once?

Comment: actually it was instead of, but i put so as both are same. sorry for the confusion

Comment: Do you have a question about  *in stead of* ? (Ie, about *in*, space, *stead*, space, *of*)  If so, ask it.  If not, delete the extra space.  -1 until then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is pretty much correct.

Another example, "Tonight we are having pasta instead of chicken for dinner."

You use "instead of" to signify choosing one thing over another without necessarily commenting on the merits of either.